# Message processing guarantee in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

In Topic type messaging systems the consumer is responsible for reporting the initial offset when he connects to the topic.

In a situation where the consumer is off, and 3 new messages are posted on the topic. When the consumer goes online, he will not read that 3 messages. Only when a 4 message is posted on the topic will it be read by the consumed

How do I ensure that all messages that are on the topic have been processed?

Answer (score 1):

You should use consumer groups for this.  When using consumer groups, the Kafka server manages the latest offset committed for the group.  Then, the next time you connect to the Kafka server, it will look up the last offset committed and place the consumer at that position.  The alternative to this would be to store your latest offsets in an external datastore (KV / RDBMS) and look them up at the application startup. You can then specify the offset to seek to after connecting to the kafka broker. https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read [this](https://medium.com/@danieljameskay/understanding-the-enable-auto-commit-kafka-consumer-property-12fa0ade7b65) post

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

We need to specify the value of the property `auto.offset.reset` in the following case.

If your consumer was reading from the partition for the first time and it crashed before committing the offset.

`auto.offset.reset` can be set to either one as given below.

**earliest**: automatically resets the offset to the earliest offset

**latest**: automatically resets the offset to the latest offset

If consumer has successfully committed the offset before getting crashed then Once it will come alive , it will start reading from the last committed offset.

Comment: I configured it to start from the beginning through my lib, but I did not get events yet

Comment: I have explained  Apache Kafka tags. I think, you need to look into your API provider definitions for this.